# How to write 8 bit unsigned integer to a file using python?

Tags: python, c++, file-handling

I want to write 8 bit unsigned integers to file. In c++ we can do it using fprintf in which the format is:

%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier

Is there any way I can do it using python?
I tried finding the size of the file by asigning value of x =1 to print only 9 integer values, I didn't understand how the file size was 35 bytes.

```
f = open('myfile','w')
while x>0:
for i in range(0,9):
    a[i] = random.randint(0,255)
    f.write("%d" % a[i])
    f.write(" ")
f.write('\n')
x = x-1
f.close()
```

[image: size of myfile]

Comment: Your code writes the textual, decimal representation of numbers in the range 0-255. Your prose indicates that you want to write the non-textual binary representation.  Do you understand the difference? If so, which do you actually want?

Comment: why shouldn't it be? you're getting some random integer from 0->255, and since you're writing out to a text file, you're getting the string representation of that number, `1` is one character/byte, `10` is two characters/bytes, `100` is 3 characters/bytes, and youre `randint()` just happened to generate numbers that come to 24 chars/bytes  (+ 10 spaces + newline)

Comment: No , I don't understand the difference :-( @Robᵩ

Comment: @MarcB I understand what you saying but I don't want to write string representation of the number, how do I write the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code writes nine 8-bit unsigned integers a file, using 1-byte-per-word binary representation.

```
import struct
import random

f = open('myfile','wb')
for i in range(0,9):
    a = random.randint(0,255)
    f.write(struct.pack("=B", a))
f.close()
```

The important features of this program are:

- it uses mode `'wb'`, not '`w`' to open the output file.
- it uses `struct.pack` to create the binary data.

Comment: By "this code", for a minute I thought you meant the OP's and was really confused. Perhaps clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in binary mode and convert the unsigned integer value into a one character string. Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
import random

with open('myfile', 'wb') as f:
    for _ in range(0, 9):
        a = random.randint(0, 255)
        f.write(chr(a))
```